# How to remove the namespace of only the root element of an XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need help in removing the namespace only from root element using XSLT.

Current:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="dfsafas.fsafs">
    <ns0:element1>abda</ns0:element1>
    <ns0:element2>abda</ns0:element2>
    <ns0:element3>abda</ns0:element3>
</ns0:root>
```

Expected:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:ns0="dfsafas.fsafs">
    <ns0:element1>abda</ns0:element1>
    <ns0:element2>abda</ns0:element2>
    <ns0:element3>abda</ns0:element3>
</root>
```

I got some solution for removing all the namespaces, but requirement is only for the first element.

This is my XSLT-1.0 approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" /> 
  <xsl:template match=""> 
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@ | node()"/> 
    </xsl:element> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post the XSLT you tried. And mention the version of XSLT you are using.

Comment: I included the XSLT-1.0 code from the comments and also changed the title and some spelling.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.  Note that the URI of the namespace now gets returned in the element* nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:ns0="dfsafas.fsafs"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your original answer was much better. Now you have too much code.

Comment: Hi Again,  I changed the code to make to make it generic.  So, this XSLT will remove the namespace from the root node of any XML. After thinking about it, I thought this is what the person asking the question was after.  That said, feel free to re-post my original answer.

Comment: "*remove the namespace from the root node of any XML*" That too can be done with a single template (in addition to the *identity transform* template) and without using modes. Just use `<xsl:template match="/*">`.

Comment: But, your suggestion is far better.  Thank you michale.hor257k.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will remove the namespace only from the root element and won't copy it into the other elements.

I found the solution after having a problem trying to render json **array** from xml using Tibco Rest & Json Plugin, so I transformed the xml to get rid of the first namespace only, and then rendered it. (got rid of only the root element to keep the xml valid and strict)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- remove namespaces -->
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- keep namespace of root element -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For this XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ns0:rootElement xmlns:ns0 = "http://www.tibco.com/namespaces/tnt/plugins/json">

<ns1:child xmlns:ns1="http://www.yourscheme.com">
<ns1:Name>Aviv</ns1:Name>
<ns1:Age>22</ns1:Age>
</ns1:child>

<ns1:child  xmlns:ns1="http://www.yourscheme.com">
<ns1:Name>Joe</ns1:Name>
<ns1:Age>Doe</ns1:Age>
</ns1:child>


</ns0:rootElement>
```

You'll get the following result:

```
<rootElement>
   <ns1:child xmlns:ns1="http://www.yourscheme.com">
      <ns1:Name>Aviv</ns1:Name>
      <ns1:Age>22</ns1:Age>
   </ns1:child>
   <ns1:child xmlns:ns1="http://www.yourscheme.com">
      <ns1:Name>Joe</ns1:Name>
      <ns1:Age>Doe</ns1:Age>
   </ns1:child>
</rootElement>
```

Comment: This question is tagged `xslt-1.0`. Your answer requires XSLT 2.0. (Not to mention that you're answering a different question.)

Comment: i'm answering exactly the question he asked BUT the xslt 1.0 vs xslt 2.0